# What to do when a question is flagged as duplicate, while new good answers are provided

Tags: discussion, questions, flags, answers, duplicate-questions

I asked a question whithout paying attention that it was already answered in StackExchange, I understand and agree that this question should be marked as duplicate.

But, what should we do when that question got new answers and suggestions which were not provided in the first one? Moreover, is it even normal that the question remain marked as duplicate?

Comment: If the answers are really new, flag your own question and ask to merge it with the duplicate. This way all answers will be in one place.

Comment: Thanks @Shadow Wizard for your suggestion, thats exactly what i will do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do either what Shadow Wizard said in the comment, flag it to merge with the duplicate question, or just leave it there. Your question might be helpful to future users and might have something the other post(s) does not. It is also a way to see which idea is better, even further helping future users and others. It is your choice really. Do it my way or Shadow Wizard's way. I hope this helps you and you keep your question for the benefit for others!